# Working with Xcode breakpoints

Tags: xcode, ide, debugging, breakpoints

I'm a CS student, so I'm still fairly new to programming. Breakpoints seemed pretty darn cool and useful to debugging, so I decided to play around with them a bit.

Unfortunately, I don't really know how to work with them. I added a breakpoint to "Log breakpoint and arguments and auto-continue". The program reached the breakpoint, the debugger console spat out some stuff, but then when the program tries to ask for user input, I see a light-blue `(gdb)` at the end.

When I press enter, nothing happens to indicate the program received the input. What am I supposed to do here?